# How can I store a 'join' query as a new table in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables as follows:

`table_1`:

```
--------------------------
    Date           Temp
--------------------------
    201309010051    82
    201309010151    81
    201309010251    80
```

and `table_2`:

```
---------------------
    Count   Temp
---------------------
    121      82
    435      81
    657      80
```

I apply a left join on both `table_1` and `table_2` using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2
ON table_1.Temp = table_2.Temp;
```

Based on the above query, how can I store the output joined table as a new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [create a new table](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE `new_tbl` (`date` datetime , `temp1` int , `count` int , `temp2` int );
```

And then you can use

```
INSERT INTO `new_tbl` SELECT * FROM table_1 LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.Temp = table_2.Temp;
```

Comment: Not so much. When you create a new table you need to give names to the columns. You can use `a1, a2, a3, a4` if you want, but you must have it

Comment: Added a link in my answer to the `create` syntax.

Comment: what do you mean by the "variable types"?

Comment: No, they are required. Check the link in my answer

Comment: Strange, I ran the query without them and it did not complain.

Comment: @Dekel In SQLite, column types [are optional](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: @CL. you'r right! Thank for the correction :) forgot that point in sqlite.